# RUN a command on build context before copying files in Docker image

Tags: docker

I have a git repository as my build context for a docker image, and i want to execute gradle build and copy the jar file into the docker image and run it on entrypoint.

I know that we can copy the entire project into the image and run build and execute, however i want to run build first and copy only the jar executable into the image.

Is it possible to execute commands in the build context before copying the files?

Current way:

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:8

COPY ./ .

RUN ./gradlew clean build

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","-c","java -jar oms-core-app-*-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

What i want:

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:8

RUN ./gradlew clean build

COPY ./oms-core-app-*-SNAPSHOT.jar .

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh","-c","java -jar oms-core-app-*-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I cannot run the ./gradlew clean build before copying the project because the files don't exist in the image when running the command. But i want to run it in the source itself and then copy the jar.

Any help would be highly appreciated thank you.

Comment: Execute your build on the host before you start `docker build`?

Comment: It's not possible since the build context is a git repository, not a project in the host.

Comment: eg:- 
build context: "https://${USERNAME}:${PASSWORD}@gitlab_url.git#${BRANCH_NAME}

Comment: You could use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

Comment: this surely looks like you trying to build a branch within a pipeline, no? If so, doesn't gitlab already has that build in? I mean, it will most probably do the same thing, but still. Btw, you do not need `clean`, since you checkout a branch, there is literally no `build` directory

Answer (score 2):

Conceptually this isn't that far off from what a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) does.  Docker can't create files or run commands on the host, but you can build your application in an intermediate image and then copy the results out of that image.

```sh
# First stage: build the jar file.
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:8 AS build
WORKDIR /app               # avoid the root directory
COPY ./ .                  # same as "current way"
RUN ./gradlew clean build  # same as "current way"
RUN mv oms-core-app-*-SNAPSHOT.jar oms-core-app.jar
                           # give the jar file a fixed name

# Second stage: actually run the jar file.
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:8 # or some JRE-only image
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/oms-core-app.jar .
CMD java -jar oms-core-app.jar
```

So the first stage runs the build from source; you don't need to run `./gradlew build` on the host system.  The second stage starts over from just the plain Java installation, and `COPY` only the jar file in.  The second stage is what eventually runs, and if you `docker push` the image it will not contain the source code.